# Calling javascript function when option is selected but need it inside the option itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

How can I do when the option is selected the function will be called with the parameters that I pass? I can't put the javascript function on select itself because I'm using `foreach` to fill my option and I also need to get my parameter defends on one column on my query

**Example:**

```
<select name="request_type" id="request_type" class="form-control" required onchange="approval(<?php()?>)">
  <option value="">Select Request Type</option>
  @foreach($types as $type)
   <option value="{{ $type->id ?? ''}}" // if selected function call(true/false)>{{ $type->name ?? ''}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

after calling the `@foreach` there will I know the column im basing whether I will pass true or false on my function on javascript. Can anyone help me on this? The column itself is a boolean.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I want to do this without using ajax. is there any other way?

Comment: FYI click event can only be bind to `select`, so far from my knowledge, we cannot add event to options.

Comment: Yeah I know that too. I'm just trying the chance of doubt if there's other way.

Comment: Is your options are getting bound with proper values?

Comment: What do you mean? my option values are the id of the `$type`

Comment: Please show an example of the rendered code, the server-side code is not useful here.

Comment: trigger `change` function for `select` on document ready, so it will fire `onChange` function. And write any logic you want inside of that `onChange` function.

Comment: @Webinion like what I said I can't do that. I need to pass a value that only exist after I call the foreach. I can't move the foreach above the select that will cause a UI problem.

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean by rendered code?

Comment: The rendered code is the code Laravel actually creates, and which is then loaded to the browser.

Comment: then what you can do is that pass one extra attribute for that value which you need to pass in `foreach` something like this `<option data-parameter="true/false"></option>` and get that value using jQuery selector.

Comment: @Webinion wait is that possible? how can I call it on javascript tho?

Comment: @Webinion do you mind right your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @jovs, yes, that's possible.  Please check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8ekbq02/) let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Webinion yes I already did it. please right your answer for the others that need it too in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger `select` change function on document ready, like mentioned in code. And for custom parameter in `option` add custom attribute in option like `data-parameter` and get value of that in change function. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/t8ekbq02/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown-id').change()
})
function callFunction(dropdown){
  var selectedOption = $(dropdown).find('option:selected')
  var customParameter = $(selectedOption).attr('data-parameter')
  console.log(customParameter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown-id" onchange="callFunction(this)">
  <option value="1" data-parameter="false">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected data-parameter="true">Two</option>
  <option value="3" data-parameter="abc">Three</option>
</select>
```